# Cloudflare Workers - SSE

Tags: javascript, events, cloudflare, fetch-api, cloudflare-workers

Is there a way to do server-side-events with cloudflare workers?
I've only found one way but it'll stop right after returning the response.

```js
    const { readable, writable } = new TransformStream();
    const response = {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      }),
      status: 101
    };

    setInterval(() => {
      const encoder = new TextEncoder();
      const writer = writable.getWriter();
      writer.write(encoder.encode(`data: hello\n\n`));
    }, 5000);

    return new Response(readable, response);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include a interval, so I updated it!

Answer (score 9):

There are two problems with your example code:

- You should not set status code 101. Status code 101 means "switching protocols", i.e. the server is going to begin speaking something other than HTTP. This is used, for example, with WebSockets. But, your example code doesn't use a different protocol -- it's just regular HTTP with a streaming response body. The Workers runtime does not support switching protocols except to WebSocket, so it will refuse to serve your 101 status code, and will instead serve an error to the client.
- You are calling `getWriter()` on every interval, but you can only have one Writer, so on intervals after the first, the call fails. You should instead call `getWriter()` once before setting the interval, then reuse that writer.

Both of these problems show up as errors in the JavaScript console when running your code in the preview (e.g. on cloudflareworkers.com, or in the Cloudflare dashboard, or using `wrangler preview` or `wrangler dev`). I recommend using the preview to debug your code, as it can tell you about errors that are invisible to the client.

The following code works for me in the preview -- text gets added to the response every 5 seconds as expected:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const { readable, writable } = new TransformStream();
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const writer = writable.getWriter();
  setInterval(() => {
    writer.write(encoder.encode(`data: hello\n\n`));
  }, 5000);

  return new Response(readable);
}
```

Comment: It does not work since there is no "Connection" and other headers it'll not work, but with the correct headers it'll work, thanks.

Comment: My example was just meant to show how to do the streaming; I don't know what other headers your app needs. But note that you cannot set the `Connection` header in Workers. However, there's no reason you should need to. The `Connection` header doesn't have any affect on streaming response bodies or SSE; it only controls whether another request can be sent on the same connection after the response body ends.

Comment: One question how would I check if the client closed.

Comment: @Tector if the client closes the connection, the Worker is immediately canceled, including canceling all outgoing fetch() requests. If you want to do something else when the client disconnects, you will need to use waitUntil() to prevent the worker from being canceled, and check for write() throwing an exception to detect the connection closure. (Note that write() returns a promise which you'll have to await to catch the exception.)